# wordpress wrong category name in url redirects to the actual category

Tags: wordpress

I have this url structure in my wordpress project:
www.example.com/category/subcategory/post

There is a weird issue where i'm entering a url with category & subcategory which do not exists - but with an existing post name, it redirects me to the relevant post.

so for instance:
I have a post named 'bitcoin' which is under the category 'reviews' and subcategory of 'trade'.

I go to - www.example.com/blabla/blulu/bitcoin
and I get redirected to - www.example.com/reviews/trade/bitcoin

I want to avoid this redirect from happening - any idea how or what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the sollution you are looking for:

```
function remove_redirect_guess_404_permalink( $redirect_url ) {
 if ( is_404() )
    return false;
 return $redirect_url;
}
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'remove_redirect_guess_404_permalink' );
```

I found this answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144937/disable-only-url-auto-complete-not-the-whole-canonical-url-system/144970#144970), but until I get reputation 50 I cannot post this as comment.

Comment: so i just need to put this in functions.php?

Comment: from some reason, this code never enters the if, even when address is wrong, any idea why?